If 2 columns of sheet 1 are a match in sheet 2 , then copy third column cell of respective row in sheet 1
I want to compare two columns in sheet 1 with two columns in sheet 2 and pull third column item from sheet 2 to sheet 1.
Sheet 1 two columns
[![These two columns are in sheet 1. I want to bring quantity column in sheet 2 to sheet][1]][1]
1(third column)
[![this is sheet 2. contains three columns. I have to match two columns in sheet 1 to 2 columns in sheet 2 and once matched, bring respective third column and row to sheet 1][2]][2]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BiwUR03SM5pEYUipv80yW2A9196fXkTUpJ-tO3884YI/edit?usp=sharing

I take it the square brackets are where images were meant to be inserted?  At the moment it just makes the question really hard to understand.


You may try:
=arrayformula(xlookup(A2:A&B2:B,Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!C:C,))


